# Is there a STL algorithm that finds last but that it also works on pointers?

Tags: c++, stl

I have existing code where I can not switch to iterators. 
Still I would like to use STL if possible to find the last item(or first if you consider we are iterating from end). 
Is that possible?

std::find_end beside being worst named algorithm ever seems quite ugly to use(I would need a fake 1 element sequence and binary predicate that ignores values of 1 element in comparison).

What I have now is quite ugly(especially since reverse of reverse of bool* is not bool* so I have to do ugly stuff to get std::distance.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{ 
    {
    bool arr[6] = {true,false,true,true,true,false};
    auto e = std::make_reverse_iterator(&arr[0]);
    auto b = std::make_reverse_iterator(&arr[6]);
    auto it = std::find(b,e, false);
    if (it!=e){
        std::cout << "index of last false is " << &(*it) - &arr[0] << std::endl;
    }
    }
    // repeat test to make sure result is not an accident
    {
    bool arr[6] = {true,false,true,true,false,true};
    auto e = std::make_reverse_iterator(&arr[0]);
    auto b = std::make_reverse_iterator(&arr[6]);
    auto it = std::find(b,e, false);
    if (it!=e){
        std::cout << "index of last false is " << &(*it) - &arr[0] << std::endl;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: From C++11,  `std::begin(arr)` and `std::end(arr)` give the begin and (past the) end iterators for an array, that can be passed to standard algorithms.    `std::rbegin()` and `std::rend()` give the corresponding reverse iterators.    Those functions work for arrays, not pointers.

Comment: `Is there a STL algorithm ... but that it also works on pointers?` All standard algorithms work with pointers. Pointers are iterators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to find the index of the last element in a container (including c arrays) is using `std::find` with `reverse_iterator`s (For bidirectional containers) just like you have tried but with less UB (`&arr[6]` is UB).

```
using std::begin;
using std::rbegin;
using std::rend;

bool arr[6] = {...};
auto it = std::find(rbegin(arr), rend(arr), false);
if (it != rend(arr)) {
    auto idx = std::distance(begin(arr), it.base()) - 1;
    std::cout << "idx is " << idx << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure &arr[6] is UB.

Comment: `arr[6]`is dereferencing the past the end element which is UB and then `&` takes the address of that element. `arr + 6` is not UB as the past the end element is not dereferenced, just pointed at.

Comment: ah yes it is UB, thanks for clarifying, but it probably compiles to same asm :P

Comment: `&arr[6]` is not UB.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I get right what you need but this code seems to work ok:

```
int arr[6] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int pattern[1] = { 4 };
auto it = std::find_end(arr, arr + 5, pattern, pattern + 1);
```